# Importing a module into js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import the 'threejs-meshline' package into my index.js file as a module. I installed it via npm, and it's in a 'node_modules' folder.

I'm trying to import it this way:

```
import {MeshLine, MeshLineMaterial, MeshLineRaycast} from 'threejs-meshline'
```

The console gives this error: "Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../"."

Adding '../node_modules/' to the beginning doesn't work.

Comment: Where and how are you running your *index.js* file? Node.js? A browser? Notice that the latter does only support full urls or paths, not plain specifiers.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you have package.json file for your project and that you have installed the `threejs-meshline` from npm by using `npm install threejs-meshline`